# From infinite dimensional function space to n-dimensional real space

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control

I am an engineering student who works in the field of optimal control. Problems in this field are typically framed in infinite dimensional Sobolev space, $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, as:

\begin{equation} \label{optimalControl}
\begin{aligned}
&J[u(t)] = \underset{u(t)}{\mathrm{minimize}} \int_{t_{0}}^{t_{f}} L(t,x(t),u(t))\hspace{0.1cm} dt \\
&s.t. \hspace{0.8cm} \dot{x}(t) = f(t,x(t),u(t)) \\
& \hspace{1.5cm}x(0) = x_{start} \\
& \hspace{1.5cm}x(t_f) = free
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where,

$\hspace{4.6cm} x(t)\in C^1[t_o,t_f]$ is state vector,

$\hspace{4.6cm}u(t)\in C^1[t_o,t_f]$ is control vector,

$\hspace{4.6cm}f[t,x(t),u(t)]$ is system dynamics,

$\hspace{4.6cm}L[t,x(t),u(t)]$ is Lagrangian, and

$\hspace{4.6cm}J[u(t)]$ is a scalar cost function

One of the methods to solve such a problem is to discretize it directly and recast it as a nonlinear program (NLP) in finite dimensional real space, $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Here is my question:

What mathematical justification do we have to solve an infinite dimensional problem by converting it to a finite dimensional problem and expect to get a correct solution? In addition to looking for some relevant theorems that allow us to do that, it will be very helpful if somebody can also help me understand this intuitively.

**Note**: After digging a bit myself, I found a theorem which may be relevant here and is called Lax Equivalence Theorem. Is this it?

Comment: I think it is similar to numerical integration using ODE solvers. So you can lower the step size to get within any arbitrary bound of the actual solution.

Comment: It probably is, and I have thought about that aspect too, but do you think if there is any fundamental difference between space and time discretization?

Comment: I would suspect not, but this would also be related to numerically solving partial differential equations, however I have little experience with that.

Comment: If $k$ is large enough, then the functions are all smooth and can be well approximated by a finite sequence of points. But otherwise, Sobolev space may contain 'weak' solutions and these cannot be as easily approximated.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. The conversion from an infinite dimensional problem to a finite-dimensional problem is a fairly well-known process given by calculus of variations. Is that not reason enough? Hamilton's principle, the Euler-Lagrange equations, Legendre transforms, and some related variational calculus topics should give you more than enough info.